# How to show the function scope in Vim?

Tags: vim

Is there any way to show the function's scope, I mean {...}, in Vim?
I use Eclipse ADT, and found that it can do it and it is a very good feature.

[image: screenshot showing eclipse functionality]

Comment: Please explain what this feature does and how/when/why you use it. Do you want to select the body of a function? Do you want to jump to its beginning/end?

Comment: https://www.box.com/s/4961fa7d47417e63a0f3      this link is safe, and I took a screenshot of my eclipse to show what I want in Vim. So just to *show* the function scope when the focus (e.g. mouse) is within the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to see function scope is to use folding (`:help fold`) and the `foldcolumn` option will provide a representation of where the folds are.

Another useful scope feature is <kbd>[</kbd><kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd><kbd>}</kbd>, which jump backward and forward to the next level of braces.

The other useful method if you're having trouble seeing the limits of a function's scope is to make your functions smaller :-)